# Why does package.json script behave differently than identical terminal command

Tags: npm, terminal, package.json, environment

In my `npm` project, in my `package.json` file, I have the following lines of code:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
```

While in my terminal, if I run `npm webpack`, I get the error message:

```
Unknown command: "webpack"
```

But if I run `npm run build`, I get a prompt from webpack saying I need webpack-cli... so the command is obviously recognized.

I'm confused about the different behavior of these two commands. In this case, isn't running `npm run build` identical to running `npm webpack` in my terminal? Why does one command fail and one succeed? What is actually happening when I run `npm run build`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#environment),

> Environment
>
> > Package scripts run in an environment where many pieces of information are made available regarding the setup of npm and the current state of the process.

> path
>
> > If you depend on modules that define executable scripts, like test suites, then those executables will be added to the PATH for executing the scripts.

Maybe this is the reason `webpack` is not recognized by the command line.